# How to mock server / http requests in Codename One for testing?

Tags: testing, codenameone, functional-testing

I want to write functional tests for my Codename One app.

To do this, I need to be able to mock some server responses, so that they return exactly what I need for the specific test.

One thing that I tried to make the functions that send the HTTP requests take ConnectionRequest as a parameter, this way I can inject something to simulate network latency and then call the callback with the mocked response.

However, when I try to inject the mocks of ConnectionRequest in the prepare method of a unit test, they are still injected after the app is started, which does not work for my case, since I sent HTTP request on the start of the app.

Is it possible to mock ConnectionRequest or do something equivalent before starting the app?

Comment: We don't have anything like this in Codename One. You might be able to hack some JavaSE mock frameworks to work with the simulator though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing. I am posting this if someone needs a workaround for the automated tests.

1. Write an interface called `HTTPRequestInterface`, which exposes the neccessary methods to construct an HTTP query
2. Create an implementation of `HTTPRequestInterface` called say `HTTPRequest`, which is just a wrapper around ConnectionRequest
3. Create a class for creating HTTPRequests, say `HTTPRequestFactory`, which has a static method called `create` and a method called `setMock`. This class creates a normal `HTTPRequest` in case no mock was set and the specified mock in case a mock was set.
4. Replace all `ConnectionRequest` with `HTTPRequestFactory.create()`
5. Create a class `InitialSetup`, which has two methods: `setInitialization`, which accepts a `Runnable` to be executed, and `init` method, which just runs the `Runnable`.
6. In the start method, call `InitialSetup.init`
7. Now in the tests, in the prepare method, I can set the desired mock, and the app when not running automated tests will send queries to the actual server.

Requires some effort, but the automated tests with mocked backend bring confidence that I think is definitely worth it!

Answer (score 1):

You can slow down connectivity in the simulator which will mock *slow connection on devices* or turn it off completely to simulate *No internet connection*. Find the options in your simulator under **Simulate** -> **Network**. Change this setting to `Slow connection` or `Disconnected` and re-run your app.

Point to a wrong URL to simulate 404 error.

Return unreadable data from your server side code to simulate IOException or NullPointer exception.

While performing this, make sure your Network Monitor is visible. Most of other responses you want could be done on your server side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the thing I want in this case is for example, a server endpoint may return two possible responses, and I want to test that the app acts appropriately for each one. Since the functional tests are automated, I can't hardcode the response in the server. I am looking for something like https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend
in Angular, basically you tell: "For this automated test, expect this HTTP request, and respond with this HTTP response". After some research, I think that this is not possible in Codename One.